# Unity Google Play Games Plugin: ERROR NOT AUTHORIZED

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play-services, google-play-games

I m developing an android Game .I'm using a real device for testing. The game uses Google Games Services. when I tried to implement the game services login authorised failed unity. the error comes only when using `EnableSavedGames()`. if i don't use `EnableSavedGames()` then i'm able to login. can anyone help me to solve this?.

```
  using GooglePlayGames;
        using GooglePlayGames.BasicApi;
        using UnityEngine.SocialPlatforms;
        PlayGamesClientConfiguration config = new PlayGamesClientConfiguration.Builder()
            // enables saving game progress.
            .EnableSavedGames()
            .Build();
        PlayGamesPlatform.InitializeInstance(config);
        // recommended for debugging:
        PlayGamesPlatform.DebugLogEnabled = true;
        // Activate the Google Play Games platform
        PlayGamesPlatform.Activate();
```

To sign in code

```
Social.localUser.Authenticate((bool success) => {
        // handle success or failure
    });
```

Comment: Is your account email in the tester section of the google play console?

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug on newly created Play Game Services projects. It's from Googles side and they are still trying to solve this problem.

https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/issues/2429

You can follow this Issue from this link. I hope they fix it soon.